# sed with seq command problem

Tags: sed, seq

With this bash script

```bash
seq=$(seq 3)
sed -i "i ${seq}" input.txt
```

I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `
'
```

But the following script works.

```bash
sed -i "i 1 2 3" input.txt
```

Why?

Comment: Don't give your variables the same name as commands - that's a recipe for shooting yourself in the foot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man sed`:

> ```
>   i \
>    text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
> ```

You have "unpreceded" newlines in your `seq` output (unlike the verbatim `1 2 3` who have spaces).